# Installing configobj for python 2.7

Tags: python, configobj

I'm sorry, I'm a Python scrub and I just wanted to make sure that I'm installing this library the right way.

I'm trying to get configObj installed for Python 2.7

Should I just browse to the directory the unzip is in and python.exe setup.py?  If I do that will it install to the correct place?  I know that seems basic but I don't work a lot with python so I just wanted to make sure since this library doesn't appear to have a windows msi.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you read the docs ? (http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html#installing). So yes, `setup.py install` should be OK

Comment: Did you read the docs is not really an answer so I guess that's why you commented rather than answering, but yes I did.  I just wanted to make sure that this would install to the python install itself and wasn't just in the unzipped directory or something like that.  I just ran it in my project directory to make sure but from what you tell me that's not necessary.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: Basically the docs says precisely the same as you did. So either you had not read them, or you were installing a Python package for the first time. That was for the question in the comment. Now based on your answer, I understand it's the second option - which is fine, but it would have been an interesting thing to know to answer properly.

Comment: documents should always be in the extracted folder called readme.  I am with you on this one.  Totally annoying to not find them in the right place.  I ask questions all the time El Duderino.  I guess other's are reader-philes.  I personally think my own personal hell will be a wall of text on a white screen with me searching for something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pip install configobj
```

Tt's the same for Linux versions also, provided you have pip.

Answer (score 0):

Following the link provided by Tibo, I installed this library with `pip install configobj`.  You can get pip on windows, following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows).